# Swagger maven provided

Tags: java, maven, swagger

My pom.xml

```
    <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
    <swagger-jersey2-jaxrs.version>1.5.16</swagger-jersey2-jaxrs.version>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-jersey2-jaxrs.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

All work fine but when I Change

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-jersey2-jaxrs.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have error

```
15:45:32,515 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear"."service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear"."service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear.service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:292)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear.service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:290)
    ... 8 more
```

I try add jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar in modules.xml in my WildFly10 but it don't help me.

How can I deploy application with provided paramter?

Comment: Are you sure that swagger-jersey2-jaxrs (in an appropriate version) is provided by the Container Wildfly 10? It seems as if Wildfly doesn't have this.

Comment: I want to transfer it to wildfly. But I can not make a mistake with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Answer (score 1):

The Maven scope

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

means that the artifact is not bundled into your artifact because you *assume* that it is provided by the container (Wildfly).

It does not, though, deploy this artifact to Wildfly or change anything in Wildfly.